# Stored Procedure Parameter Type

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, types

I have a question about the **in parameter type** of a stored procedure. Normally the definition of a parameter will look like this:

```
in param_test VARCHAR(100)
```

Do you know if I can defined a parameter like this?:

```
in param_test table.column%type
```

This way the parameter will be the same type as the column of an specific table. So if the column type change from varchar(100) to varchar(250) I don't have to change the parameter type in the stored procedure.

I know It's possible in Oracle, but I don't know if it is in MySQL.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax is not supported in MySQL. You need to explicitly declare the datatype for a parameter in a stored program.

If you want to protect yourself from future changes to the max length of a varchar column, you can just use the `TEXT` datatype for the parameter,

Answer (score -1):

how to pass parameter value to database of text datatype..
i am using this code
mysql_CommandLtp.Parameters.Add("@prmName", MySqlDbType.Text);
mysql_CommandLtp.Parameters["@prmName"].Value = prmName.ToString().Trim();

Comment: The OP asked for a solution in MySQL, not in a programming language.